# How to redirect to previous URL after Facebook Passport without sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I'm trying to redirect back to the link in the referer header, but the request on the facebook callback doesn't contain a referer header.

```
app.get(
    // referer present
    '/login/facebook',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'], session: false }),
);

app.get(
    // referer not present
    '/login/facebook/return',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: config.CLIENT_URI, session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        const { secret, expiresIn } = config.jwt;
        const id = Array.isArray(req.user) ? req.user[0].id : req.user.id;

        // Redirect to client
        const token = jwt.sign({ id }, secret, { expiresIn });

        if (req.headers.referer) {
            res.redirect(`${req.headers.referer}?token=${token}`);
        } else {
            res.redirect(`${config.CLIENT_URI}?token=${token}`);
        }
    },
);
```

How do I redirect back to the referer? I don't want to use sessions.